# What is the difference between this loop using array bracket vs pointer notation in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, post-increment

In the C programming language, I have the following code:

```
void rm_newline(char input[])
{
    assert(input);
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if(input[i] == '\n') input[i] = '\0';
    }
    return;
}
```

This code works as intended by replacing a '\n' char with '\0'. However I had a previous version shown below:

```
void rm_newline(char input[])
{
    assert(input);
    char *input_ptr = input;
    while(*input_ptr != '\0')
    {
        if(*input_ptr++ == '\n')
        {
            *input_ptr = '\0';
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

This second code was not properly replacing the '\n' with '\0' but I'm not sure why. Would someone please explain how the second code is functionally different from the first code?

Comment: `*input_ptr++` The pointer is incremented after checking the character. So when `\n` is found the next line is setting the wrong byte (one after the `\n`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case,

```
 if(*input_ptr++ == '\n')
```

`input_ptr` is incremented before the body of the conditional executes. You need to increment after the replacement is done, something like

```
while(*input_ptr != '\0')
{
    if(*input_ptr == '\n')
    {
        *input_ptr = '\0';  
    }
     input_ptr++; // do the increment here
}
```

Comment: Would this not create an infinite loop though, if the first character in the char array wasn't `\n`? Because the increment would only occur after the character is `\n`.

Comment: @the_endian Right, just noticed and modified.